# Text aligning and cutting of if too long

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm creating an app and i want the text to allign under a button, it looks like this:
[image]

so i want the large text starting on the left at(5dp) under the button and end at(155dp from the left) the end of the button. And if the text is too long to fit under the button, i don't want it to go in the next line, i want it to cut of and put in ".." at the end so, that it looks like this f.e. "Large T..", i photoshoped that picture real quick to show you what i mean:

[image]

I'm kind of new to xml and the whole ndroid app scene, so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: is your large text dynamic ?

Comment: as i said, i'm new to this, so please excuse, but i don't have a clue on what you mean with "dynamic", or how i could check if it's dynamic

Comment: can you show your layout xml?

Comment: are you setting text in your xml file or you are getting string from some service and setting text in your java file

Comment: you can give table view a go. you can easyly center things in the cells

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinearLayouts` with `layout_wight`. Example code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your TextView add these properties:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxEms="8"
android:singleLine="true"
```

NOTE: You can adjust the ems size to how many chars you want to show.